# How to retrieve listview focus in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a base adapter that works as class helper to set a custom listview. Now everything works fine except if I try to set another base adapter, The listview loses its focus of the item that I was on before setting it. I don’t know if there is a way that could help me to retrieve the same focus on the same item. Thank you very much in advance.

This is my base adapter class:

```
    class CustomAdapterWithImages extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public CustomAdapterWithImages(){
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) Home.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ids_list.size();//listview item count. 
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position; 
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder vh;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(vh);
           }else{
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
           }            

        TextView book = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewBookName);
        TextView writer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewWriterName);     
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewImage);

        try{
            book.setText(names_list.get(position));
            writer.setText(writers_list.get(position));       
            image.setImageBitmap(thumbnails_list.get(position));
        }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

 class ViewHolder{
    TextView book, writer;
    ImageView image;
    }
}
```

By calling base adapter class I can set my listview as shown below:

```
listview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapterWithImages());
```

Answer (score 0):

You would like to mark the same item as selected/focused after replacing the adapter?
If so, you can pass the position of the selected item to your new adapter and evaluate it in **getView(...)**.
The items in the list should have onClickListeners to set the index of the selected position.
That's at least one way I can imagine you can do what you want when I got it right.

If you like to update your list, because some data in you adapter changed, you can call just
**yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** instead of creating a new one.

---

At first I would suggest you change the BaseAdapter to an ArrayAdapter.
I don't know if it's possible to add items to a BaseAdapter but according to the API
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html there are no such methods.
An ArrayAdapter allows you to put objects into your adapter by calling the methods **add()** and **addAll()**.
In those methods you can put your single image or all and after it's done you just need to call **notifyDataSetChanged()** and your list will update automatically.

You can implement an *onItemClickListener* the way *Ashish Bindal* did. Attach it to your list e.g. in the place you set your adapter for your list. The *position* parameter is the index of the item that the listener is attached to and it's what you may be looking for. Everytime an item is clicked, you have to store it's position somewhere outside the *onItemClickListener* .

In your custom adapter add a new field (e.g. private int selectedItemPosition;) and a setter method to set this field.
In **getView()** you have to check if the value of the *position* parameter is equal to the value of your field *selectedItemPosition*. If it is, *convertView* is the item you can focus on.

Before calling **notifyDataSetChanged()** you have to set the position of the selected item in your adapter by using the setter method.

***BUT***
This only works if the item order won't change and the item won't be missing.

What you really need is something you can use to uniquely distinguish the items.
One of the parameters of **setOnItemClickListener()** is an ArrayAdapter. You can access the object attached to the clicked list item by calling arrayAdapters method **getItemAtPosition(position)**. If your object has a unique property e.g. an ID, this is great. If it has not you may wrap it in custom object with e.g. an ID or other unique property. 
So instead of the position in your listener you grab the unique property and pass it to your adapter.

Good luck.

Comment: Exactly. I want to update my adapter with images after they has been downloaded. But I don't know how to do it. Could you please go further and explain little bit more about updating adapter data? Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Attach item click listener with listView and save the last selected position. After setting the base adapter, set the appropriate selected position/item.

```
//set the selected item according after changing anther base adapter
listview.setSelection(appropriatePosition)

//To find last selected item position
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
        lastSlectedPosition = position;
        //or get reference to unique item in your list from the position if you are changing the dataset also.
    }
}
```